# Boolean selecting column from set of columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have sort of the following situation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_data = {'CODE' : ['111', '222', '333', '444'],
           'A' : ['2017/01/01', '2017/01/02', '', ''],
           'B' : ['', '2017/01/02', '', '2017/01/30'],
           'C' : ['', '2017/01/12', '', '2017/02/02'],
           'PRICE_A' : [10, 10, np.nan, np.nan],
           'PRICE_B': [np.nan, 8, np.nan, 9],
           'PRICE_C': [np.nan, 19, np.nan, 16]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
df.A = pd.to_datetime(df.A)
df.B = pd.to_datetime(df.B)
df.C = pd.to_datetime(df.C)
df
```

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrZf8.jpg)

Every column tells me about the reached status of the 'code' item, and of course the status is reached when a date populates the slot. At each status corresponds a price value, printed out in the PRICE_A, PRICE_B, PRICE_C corresponding columns.

What I wanted to do was adding a new column giving out the the current reached status price for each row:

[result_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScgLy.jpg)

This was easy to do taking my columns right out of the box and writing a function iterating over the arrays, but I'm sure there are better ways of achieving this with Pandas.

I wonder if someone could suggest a smarter answer to this problem.

Comment: No, it's not a max between the columns. If a column has a value, then the status corresponding to that column name is reached. So if I got values in A that means status A was reached, whereas if I got values in A and B that means right now we are in B status reached: the corresponding prices could be equal or different, but in case A I need the A_PRICE, in case B I need B price and so on.

Comment: I almost answered your question then you removed your post :( Anyway, Jezrael's basically answered it, just not 100%:

t = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A','B','C', 'CODE']);

def f(x):
    if x.last_valid_index() is None:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x[x.last_valid_index()]

t.groupby(by='CODE')['value'].apply(f);

Comment: Hey Simon, sorry, but I thought it was a  duplicated question at that point. But I'm not sure why Jezrael'answer could be not 100% right, could you explain?